# Google Charts - Wrong mouse coordinates when using 'zoom' CSS property

Tags: charts, google-visualization

When applying `zoom` or any `transform` CSS to a google chart div, or it's parent divs, the chart's mouse events will break, whenever you hover an element it will think your cursor it's a few pixels off from where it's actually is.

Lots of other libraries also have this problem because they do not account for the zoom CSS when making calculations with the mouse coordinates received via events.

Here's a similar case with fullcalendar.io: [Wrong mouse coordinates when using css zoom property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127819/wrong-mouse-coordinates-when-using-css-zoom-property)

In this case the solution was to change the API function that calculates the mouse coordinate, since I cannot do that with google charts, I'm searching for an alternate solution.

Comment: not sure, but this answer might help --> [Google charts line graph: Tooltip Hitbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70670042/5090771)

Comment: For this problem I think you need to wrap your chart container with another element and move your styles to that element.

Comment: @dlaliberte, doesn't matter how many wrapper divs i use, if any n-parent of the chart has the 'zoom' css, it will mess up the mouse cordinates on that chart.

Comment: @WhiteHat, hmmm maybe?, idk, gonna have to try it.